# on event of firebase is not working with AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

In the following event .once event is working fine

```
'use strict';

let firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = function(event, context)
{
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: {},
        databaseURL: "https://harmanconnectedcar-180411.firebaseio.com/"
    });

    firebase.database().ref('events').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       console.log("*************event**********************")
       console.log (snapshot.val()) ;
        context.succeed() ;
    });


       var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('events' );
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("*************snapshot*****snapshot*****************")
    console.log (snapshot.val()) ;
    context.succeed();
})
```

}

When i try starCountRef.on i am not able to see the logs printed

Once i put the lambda function in AWS and write to firebase from firebase console i am not able to see the events where do i need to see the logs how to check starCountRef.on  event(i mean the real time logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting two asynchronous listeners. Then when the first of them finishes you call `context.succeed()`. At that point Lambda terminates your function, so the second listener never completes.

To makes this code work, you need to ensure you only call `context.succeed()` when all of the data has loaded. An easy way to do this is by using `Promise.all()`:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context)
{
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: {},
        databaseURL: "https://harmanconnectedcar-180411.firebaseio.com/"
    });


    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('events' );

    var promises = [];
    promises.push(firebase.database().ref('events').once('value'));
    promises.push(starCountRef.once('value');

    Promises.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val();
      });
      context.succeed();
    });
}
```

Comment: just removed context.succeed() in the above code that works fine but Lambda function function was timed out after 30 seconds i am getting how do i keep live forever

Comment: The `context.succeed()` signals to Lambda that the function is done with its work. It's a crucial part of running in a serverless/FaaS environment. If you don't want to call `context.succeed()` you might as well save yourself the hassle and run on a regular Node.js environment.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up two technologies here.

The `onWrite` method is an construct of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which (as far as I know) cannot be deployed on Amazon lambda.

If you want to access your Firebase Realtime Database from Amazon Lambda, you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). But that doesn't include a way to trigger your code whenever the database is written.

Comment: That changes the question drastically, so I posted a separate answer.

Comment: any update?can i listen data write event on firebase from aws lambda?